# reuse macro for in-text equations using arguments

Tags: math-mode, macros, equations, environments, renewcommand

I am defining a macro for an equation that I use several times in my manuscript. However, I am reaching the point where I have two **almost identical** macros for the denominator and numerator of my equation (1) below. Is there any way to include arguments to change the subindex from `i` to `j`, re-using my macro?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\vMNL{
    \alpha_{i} +  
    \boldsymbol{\beta}'\boldsymbol{x}_{int}
    + 
    \left(
        \boldsymbol{z}_{n\bullet}
    \right) 
    \boldsymbol{A}
    \boldsymbol{x}_{int}}


\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $V_{int} = \vMNL{}$, consetetur sadipscing
elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat:
    
\begin{align*}
V_{int} = \vMNL{}
\end{align*}

Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.

\begin{align}\label{eq:MNL-proba-simple}
P_{int}= \dfrac{\exp
    \left( 
\vMNL{}
    \right)}
{\sum_{j=1}^{J}\exp
    \left(
    % V_{jnt}
    \alpha_{j} +
    \boldsymbol{\beta}'\boldsymbol{x}_{jnt} +
    \boldsymbol{z}_{n}  \boldsymbol{\alpha} \boldsymbol{x}_{jnt} 
    \right)}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

1. make the argument to `\mVNL` optional so you don't need to specify it when it's missing
2. use `\bm` from `bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`
3. don't overuse `\left` and `\right` (no case here needs them)
4. use `equation` for single equations
5. never have a blank line before a math display
6. define a command for the “signpost”; you use `\bullet`, but you might change your mind later and in this case you can just modify the definition of `\blank`, rather than chasing through the document for `\bullet`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand\vMNL[1][]{%
  \alpha_{#1} + \bm{\beta}'\bm{x}_{#1 nt} +%
  (\bm{z}_{n\blank))\bm{A}\bm{x}_{#1 nt}%
}
\newcommand{\blank}{{\bullet}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $V_{int} = \vMNL$, consetetur sadipscing
elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat:
\begin{equation*}
V_{int} = \vMNL[i]
\end{equation*}
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:MNL-proba-simple}
P_{int}= \frac{\exp(\vMNL[i])}{\sum_{j=1}^{J}\exp(\vMNL[j])}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @egreg. Could you elaborate further on the usage of `\bm` or give me some references for it?

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas `\bm` is a better version of `\boldsymbol`; more robust and better in several instances. You actually don't need to change all of your `\boldsymbol` calls, because the `bm` package makes it an alias for `\bm`.

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed the usage of `\newcommand{\blank}{{\bullet}}`. Could you tell me the point of it? Is it just Aesthetic or some actual functionality?

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas You can decide what `\blank` prints. I'll add something, I forgot the mental note I made.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an answer, but I am not sure if the optimal one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\vMNL[1]{
    \alpha_{#1 } +  
    \boldsymbol{\beta}'\boldsymbol{x}_{#1 nt}
    + 
    \left(
    \boldsymbol{z}_{n\bullet}
    \right) 
    \boldsymbol{A}
    \boldsymbol{x}_{#1 nt}}


\begin{document}
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $V_{int} = \vMNL{}$, consetetur sadipscing
elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat:
    
\begin{align*}
V_{int} = \vMNL{i}
\end{align*}

Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.

\begin{align}\label{eq:MNL-proba-simple}
P_{int}= \dfrac
{\exp\left(\vMNL{i}\right)}
{\sum_{j=1}^{J}\exp\left(\vMNL{j}\right)}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image]